# Redefine protocol functions using constraints without having to expose method

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift-protocols

## Ugly 1

```
protocol Persisting {
    func persist()
}

extension Persisting {
    func persist() { print("persisting") }
}

protocol Service {
    func get()
    func persistIfAble() // If I remove this, "Not able to persist" gets printed twice
}

extension Service {
    func get() {
        persistIfAble()
    }
}

extension Service {
    func persistIfAble() {
        print("Not able to persist")
    }
}

extension Service where Self: Persisting {
    func persistIfAble() {
        persist()
    }
}

struct OnlyService: Service {}
struct Both: Service, Persisting {}

let both = Both()
both.get()

let onlyService = OnlyService()
onlyService.get()
print("Can now directly call `persistIfAble` which is not wanted")
onlyService.persistIfAble() // DONT WANT THIS TO BE POSSIBLE
```

This solution would be elegant if I could remove `func persistIfAble()` from protocol declaration. Because I do not want it to be exposed. **However**, what is really interesting is that if I remove it, then the behavior changes, then the implementation inside `extension Service where Self: Persisting` never gets called.

## Ugly 2

```
protocol Persisting {
    func persist()
}

extension Persisting {
    func persist() { print("persisting") }
}

protocol Service {
    func get()
}

extension Service {
    func get() {
        // Ugly solution, I do not want to cast, `Service` should not have to know about `Persisting`
        if let persisting = self as? Persisting {
            persisting.persist()
        } else {
            print("not able to persist")
        }
    }
}

extension Service where Self: Persisting {
    func persistIfAble() {
        persist()
    }
}

struct OnlyService: Service {}
struct Both: Service, Persisting {}

let both = Both()
both.get()

let onlyService = OnlyService()
onlyService.get()
```

The code in both ugly solutions is of course an extremely simplified version of my actual scenario, where I really do not want to perform casts, because it makes the code so much more difficult to read. Even if I would change `if let` to `guard let`.

## Ugly 3 (ugliest?)

```
protocol Persisting {
    func persist()
}

extension Persisting {
    func persist() { print("persisting") }
}

protocol Service {
    func get()
    func persistIfAble(allowed: Bool)
}

extension Service {
    func get() {
        persistIfAble(allowed: true)
    }
}

extension Service {
    func persistIfAble(allowed: Bool = false) {
        guard allowed else { print("KILL APP"); return }
        print("Not able to persist")
    }
}

extension Service where Self: Persisting {
    func persistIfAble(allowed: Bool = false) {
        guard allowed else { print("BREAKING RULES"); return }
        persist()
    }
}

struct OnlyService: Service {}
struct Both: Service, Persisting {}

let both = Both()
both.get()

let onlyService = OnlyService()
onlyService.get()
print("Can now directly call `persistIfAble` which is not wanted")
// DONT WANT THIS TO BE POSSIBLE
onlyService.persistIfAble() // prints: "KILL APP"
```

## What am I missing?

Where is the beautiful solution?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if maybe what you really want is to use composition of actual objects, not just interfaces (and some default implementations). Consider this: Both `Persisting` and `Service` as you've defined them really need to be implemented in concrete classes or structs, so that they can contain context about where they are accessing their data. So I'd imagine that you could skip the protocol extensions, leave the real "guts" up to concrete implementations of those protocols, and then something like your `Both` would be implemented like this:

```
struct Both: Persisting, Service {
    let persisting: Persisting
    let service: Service
    // a default init lets you pass in concrete implementations of both of those things

    func persist() {
        persisting.persist()
    }

    func get() {
        service.get()
        persist()
}
```

This obviously doesn't give you the automatic sort of "mix-in" effect that it looks like you're trying to achieve, but OTOH it's pretty clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing one level of indirection (i.e. 'persistIfAble')?

```
protocol Persisting {
    func persist()
}

extension Persisting {
    func persist() {
        print("persisting")
    }
}

protocol Service {
    func get()
}

extension Service where Self: Persisting {
    func get() {
        persist()
    }
}

extension Service {
    func get() {
        print("Not able to persist")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont help me so much since the get method is the one where I would like to share all the code, I can of course try to wrap as much code as possible in other functions, but I would really like to be able to avoid code duplication.